# Ubuntu 12.04 Server monitor goes into sleep mode (no display) after fresh install

Tags: 12.04, server, display, monitor

For some reason I can boot and either use Ubuntu 12.04 server edition, or desktop version.  I can live boot the disk, I can go through the installer, or even use the ubuntu alternate installer. But for some reason after the install completes and I reboot the monitor seems to go back into sleep mode and then never loads the command prompt.

This is on an industrial adlink MXE-1300 PC.  I've installed ubuntu server fine on other models of adlink machines but this one doesn't want to seem to play nice.  To me it seems like if it was a video card issue than I could never even load the installer or run ubuntu in live mode.

Any thoughts or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.